# Unresolved reference lit when adding a string constant as a column in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I'm trying to add a string constant as a new Column in pyspark. I'm using 2.4.4 version of spark.
I'm using this

`data.withColumn("currentdate", lit(constant_name))`

I'm getting error "Unresolved reference lit". It seems like there is no function lit in 2.4.4 from error but when I saw documentation, it was there.

Comment: have you imported spark functions ?

Comment: yes I have imported spark function using this
" from pyspark.sql.functions import * "

Comment: try this - from pyspark.sql.functions import F & use F.lit(constant_name)

Comment: I think you want to say that try this, 
" import pyspark.sql.functions as F " and it works for me
Thanks

Comment: yes, correct sorry for typo .. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install [pyspark-stubs](https://pypi.org/project/pyspark-stubs/) package in order for your IDE to resolve the references to many of the Spark SQL functions including `lit` i.e.

```
pip install pyspark-stubs==2.4.0.post8
```

Comment: issue was solved using 
import pyspark.sql.functions as F